# Where should I put ","?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

The function below is currently what I have however, I get an error saying `',' expected`. The problem is I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.

```
async function: play(bot, ops, data) {

    data.dispatcher = await data.connection.play(ytdl(data.queue[0].url, {filter: 'audioonly'}));

    data.dispatcher.guildID = data.guildID;

    data.dispatcher.once('end', function(){
        finish(bot, ops, this);
    });
}
```

Comment: does it says the location of the missing comma?

Comment: Is the colon here required? `async function: play`

Comment: I was gonna say typescript maybe for the `function: ` but doesn't look like it. just remove the color

Comment: Oh is this a function inside of module.exports, you can just do `async play()`

Comment: As others have said, this `async function: play(bot, ops, data)` does not look right.  Please show the whole code context for that.  If this is a property definition, then it should be `play: async function(bot, ops,data) {...}`.  The property name goes to the left of the colon.  In newer versions of JS, you can also use shortcuts like `async play(bot, ops,data) {...}`.  But, in either case, your colon is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. The error is coming from line 65, which is the `async function: play(bot, ops, data) {`. But if you want to look further on my code, here it is: https://paste.nomsy.net/ezisazesug.hs

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code (I think) :

1. You should replace your play function declaration with `async play(...) {...}`
2. On the line before declaring your function is a `,` which I think should not be there

Hope this will help :)

Comment: It says it expected it, not that it wasn't there so probably not error 2, also says it was on line 65, which was that function line. If there was a comma before the function it would probably need to be there since its `module.exports` and people usually put `run()` as the last property